# How is the Lorentz group, $\text{O}(1,3)$, defined using set theoretic notation?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, special-relativity

**Context**

I am studying special relativity. I am trying to understand how to define the *group elements* of the *Lorentz group*, $\text{O}(1,3)$.  I understand from [1]  that the Lorentz group is has (at least 3) subgroups. These are  $\text{O}^+(1,3)$, $\text{SO}(1,3)$ and $\text{SO}^+(1,3)$. From [1],

> Every element in $\text{O}(1,3)$ can be written as the semidirect product of a proper, orthochronous transformation [i.e., an element of $\text{SO}^+(1,3)$] and an element of the discrete group $\left\{1, P, T, PT\right\}$, where P and T are the parity and time reversal operators [i.e., $P = \textrm{diag}(1, −1, −1, −1)$ and $T = \textrm{diag}(−1, 1, 1, 1)$].

This quote makes clear how $\text{O}(1,3)$ and $\text{SO}^+(1,3)$ are related to each other. This fact is referred to by @arctic tern in his/her answer in [2]. However, this quote does not help me define $\text{O}(1,3)$.

To be clear what I am looking for is something like a set theoretic definition of $\text{O}(1,3)$. Something like what I see in the example of Lie groups found in [3].

For example, I believe that $\text{O}(1,3)\subset \text{GL}(4, \mathbb{R})$. Therefore, I should be able to define the Lorentz group with some additional predicates.

$$\text{O}(1,3) \equiv \left\{M\in \text{GL}(4, \mathbb{R}) \mid \operatorname{Predicate 1}, \operatorname{Predicate 2}, \ldots \operatorname{Predicate n}\right\}.$$

The Lorentz group is given as an *orthogonal group*. However, though the inverse of the *Lorentz boosts* are equal to the transpose of the *Lorentz boosts*, it does not appear that the the inverse of the *Lorentz rotations* are equal to the transpose of the *Lorentz rotations*.

**Question**

How is the Lorentz group, $\text{O}(1,3)$, defined using set theoretic notation?

**Bibliography**

[1]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#boost

[2]
[Difference between the Lorentz group and the restricted Lorentz group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204349/difference-between-the-lorentz-group-and-the-restricted-lorentz-group/2204363#2204363)

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\eta = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$. Then

$$O(1, 3) = \{ M \in GL_4(\mathbb{R}) : M\,\eta\,M^T = \eta \}.$$

This condition is equivalent to the condition that $M$ preserves the Minkowski / Lorentzian inner product on 4-vector $v$ and 4-vector $w$ as

$$(v, w) = -v_0 \,w_0 + v_1\, w_1 + v_2 \,w_2 + v_3\, w_3.$$

In other words, $(M\,v, M\,w) = (v, w)$, which is the condition used by the Wikipedia article. This is because $(v, w)$ can be written $v \cdot \eta\,w$ where $\cdot$ is the usual dot product. Thus,
$$(Mv, Mw) = Mv \cdot \eta\,M\,w = v \cdot M^T \,\eta\,M\,w.$$
Setting this equal to $(v, w) = v \cdot \eta\,w$ for all $v, w$ gives the desired result (after taking one last transpose).

This is why you don't get that the inverse is the transpose (which would define the ordinary orthogonal group $O(4)$). Instead, we have $M^{-1} = \eta\,M^T \,\eta^{-1}$. Said another way, there is a *Lorentzian transpose* we should be taking here instead.

One last note. There is a sign ambiguity. Specifically, we could replace $\eta$ with $-\eta$ in the definition of $\eta$ and still get the same Lorentz group.

Comment: ok. I worked through everything. I have one last comment. Would it not be better to add another predicate to your list. Namely, that $\left[ \det(M) = +1 \lor  \det(M) = -1\right] ?$

Comment: @Michael: that's automatic. Taking the determinant of $M \eta M^T = \eta$ gives $\det(M)^2 = 1$.